# Get task duration from old timestamps

Tags: org-mode, hooks

Assuming I have a task where I store a timestamp for every taskchange I do:

```
* DONE Extremely important dummy task         :categorywhatevs:
- State "DONE"       from "IN PROGRESS" [2015-06-08 Mo 14:19]
- State "In PROGRESS"       from "URGENT"     [2015-06-04 Do 08:36]
- State "URGENT"     from "QUEUE"      [2015-06-04 Do 08:09]
- State "QUEUE"      from ""           [2015-06-04 Do 08:09]
```

These timestamps contain valuable information: Theoretically I can deduce how long a distinct task took me. We even can think about an outlook and have an analysis which measures the average task duration - certainly good for planning ahead.

But here I have a problem: How do I get this information? Of course I could string-parse everything under the task and store the durations within some property tags. I could do this automatically by using a hook (the `org-after-todo-state-change-hook` seems to be a good candidate). However as a complete lisp newbie I do not know how I got the information in upper two lines below a heading.